# PHP : Getting one value from a PDO query

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

So this is what im having trouble with right now

```
try {
    $p = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM players INNER JOIN teams ON players.teamid = teams.id WHERE players.teamid = 1');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error fetching list of players!';
    exit();
}
```

I understand this whole code nothing is wrong with it I am using a foreach loop with a table to display all the players #, Names, and Positions they are enclosed in `<tr> <td> </td> </tr>`

```
foreach($p as $player){
    echo $player['jersey'];
    echo $player['playername'];
    echo $player['position'];
}
```

This part works good too what I am having trouble accomplishing is on top of this table to display inside header tags something like this, I have tried this and get a error

```
<h1><?php $p['teamname']; ?></h1>
```

If I use fetch it removes the first player from the loop

```
$row = $p->fetch();
```

Comment: $rows = $p->fetchAll(); Then $rows[0]['teamname']... then loop through the results foreach($rows as $player)

Comment: Show how you use `fetch`!!

Comment: @KV. Thanks that worked like a charm. One question just so I can learn from it why does $rows[0] make this work without it nothing shows up? Let me rephrase that $rows['teamname'] does not work without [0] index 0 before it.

Comment: `$rows[0]` is the first row fetched in a `fetchAll()`, then `['teamname']` is returned from that row. You can specify other rows by changing the number.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks jay forgot fetch gets rows not just results

Comment: `fetch()` returns one row at a time, where `fetchAll()` returns all of the rows.

Comment: @ChristopherOrtiz Because $rows is an array with all rows. So you must type the index of the result you want. In your case it's zero. Just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `$p` is your PDO statement. You just need to fetch all rows at once:

`$rows = $p->fetchAll();`

Then `$rows` will be an array containing all rows. So the first one is:

`$rows[0]['teamname']`

Then you loop through the result set as usual:

`foreach($rows as $player)`

Comment: Note that `fetchAll` can be extremely costly if you have a large result set. It's much better to fetch one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`$p` is a `PDOStatement` which represents your entire query and result set. `'teamname'` is only a column in one of the result rows, not a property in `$p` itself. You need to fetch a row and read the value from there. However, if you then also want to iterate over all rows, including the one you already fetched, the best language construct to do this is a `do..while`:

```
$row = $p->fetch();

echo $row['teamname'];  // outputs column of first row

do {
    echo $row['jersey'];
    ...
} while ($row = $p->fetch());
```

You can output values from the first result row before the loop, and then loop over all the rest while also using that first row in the first iteration.

Answer (score -2):

In your example `$p` is your query. The query is an array of the result items. When you want to access the property `teamname` you therefore need to access the item and not the query as a whole.

In your case, that would be:

```
$p[0]['teamname'];
```

But because it could be the case that there was not a single player in one team, a much cleaner solution would be to start a whole new query just for the teamname.

```
try {
    $p = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM teams WHERE players.teamid = 1');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error fetching team name!';
    exit();
}

if(count($p) != 1)
{
    //Handle error in case team doesn't exist
}
{
    $teamname = $p[0]["teamname"];
    echo $teamname;
}
```

Furthermore it would be helpful to see the exception that came up in your example.

Comment: You still have to fetch the results before you can access the data.

Comment: In my example I received a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array so `$p[0]['teamname'] ` would throw the same error i believe.